# Getting undefined element using cfhttp

Tags: coldfusion, cfhttp, cfloop

I'm trying to get my script to read a csv file, loop through the lines (which are of urls) and see the http status code of each url.

This is the script I am using:

```
<cffile action="read" file="e:\domains\myurl.com\data\testURLs.csv" variable="csvfile"> 


<cfloop index="index" list="#csvfile#" delimiters="#chr(10)##chr(13)#">
   <cfset status = "">
      <cfoutput>
          <p>#index#</p>
             <cfhttp url="#index#" method="get" result="myresult"></cfhttp>
             <cfset status = "#myresult.statuscode#">
          <p>#status#</p>
     </cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

When I run it with a URL in the cfhttp url tag it works fine, however it doesnt work when it is set as a variable. And is giving me a "Element STATUSCODE is undefined in MYRESULT".

Would anyone be able to point out where I am going wrong?

Comment: *doesnt work when it is set as a variable.* Using a variable makes no difference, but the value it contains does. Dump the variables. What are the values of `index` and `myresult`?

Comment: So when I dump `index`, I get a list of all of the URLs. However when I try to dump out the `myresults` it errorrs the page and reports `Variable MYRESULT is undefined `

Comment: It seems like the index variable isnt being run in the cfhttp

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. Rather than describing the results, it would save time to just post them. Please output and post the results of this: <p>Current URL = #index#</p>.

Comment: index might be a reserved word. I'd try changing that variable to a different name.

Comment: I feel like you must have a typo. One time you said `myresults` but your code says `myresult`. One time it's a status code and another time is undefined. Add `<cfabort/>` after `<p>#status#</p>`. Maybe something else on the page is erroring out since we can't see the entire page. However, you said it runs fine if you put in a URL manually. Does `index` contain a single URL or the whole list of URLs. It needs to contain a single URL. Your first comment said it contains a list of URLS.

Comment: Wrap `<cfset status = "#myresult.statuscode#">` in a cftry. In the `cfcatch`, use `<cfdump var="#myresult#">` to see what's going on.